# Should expanding one row collapse other rows?

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, user-expectation, tables

Non-collapsing: http://fiddle.jshell.net/whytheday/2Dj7Y/11/show/

Collapsing: http://fiddle.jshell.net/QLfMU/116/show/

The collapsing behavior saves the user a click or a scroll. It would prevent a user from comparing the information from two different rows. My opinion is that the collapsing behavior is annoying/intrusive.

Are there any other significant advantages/disadvantages to auto-collapsing?

Comment: where are you planning to use accordion style? Is it for tables or in general?

Comment: Take  look to [this related question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/101457).

Answer (score 1):

**Auto-collapsing**

> Advantage

- Cognitive load is reduced as hence increase efficiency of readability

> Disadvantage

- Can't see data of others rows as it get collapsed automatically and hence users are forced to click each time to view data

**When not to use auto-collapsing**

In a situation where time in more important over data. To understand it
better let's take a example from telecom industry.

Imagine a person sitting in support center, for him attending support call and at the same time operating user interface could be difficult.

Because this is limitation of humans that we can not focus two thing in same modality at same time, as simple as we can't read two newspaper in same time.